# Append multiple sheets from multiple Excel files in R

Tags: r, excel, append

I am trying to append multiple sheets from multiple Excel files. For instance, each Excel file has 10 sheets (different format), but the 10 sheets of an Excel file have the same names and format as the associated 10 sheets of another Excel file. Essentially, each Excel file holds the different types of information of a different country, but the types of information collected are the same for each country (population, pollution index, GDP, etc.). And I have many countries so I'm thinking of using a loop.

I use "report_1h" as the master Excel file, and append sheets of other Excel files into the master file's sheets.

```
library(rio)

x1_data <- import_list("report_1h.xlsx")

report_list <- list.files(path = 'E:/Report_folder', pattern = '*.xlsx')

sheet_ <- data.frame()

for (file in report_list){
  book <- import_list(file)
  for (i in 1:31){
  sheet_[i] <- rbind(x1_data[[i]][,],book[[i]][,])
  x1_data[[i]][,] <- sheet_[i]
  }
}
```

The loop is intended to append sheets from each Excel file to sheets of the master file "report_1h". But it gives error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c("Data Source(s):", "Data Source(s):",  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Sorry, there are 31 sheets in each Excel file, not 10 sheets.

Comment: So if you have 10 excel files each with 31 sheets. Do you want to combine all the sheet1 from 10 files in one dataframe then 10 files from sheet2 in another and similarly you'll have 31 dataframes in the end?

Comment: Yes I want to combine all the sheet1 of all 10 excel files together, all sheet2 of all 10 excel files. So in the end I have 31 dataframes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this -

```
library(tidyverse)

#get the all the filenames
report_list <- list.files(path = 'E:/Report_folder', pattern = '*.xlsx$')

#Create a list of dataframes
map(report_list, function(x) {
  sheets <-excel_sheets(x)
  map(sheets, function(y) read_excel(x, y))
}) %>% transpose() %>%
  map(bind_rows) -> result

#assign sheet names
names(result) <- paste0('Sheet', seq_along(result))

#Write master excel file
writexl::write_xlsx(result, 'master_excel.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it soon!